# Docker impossible setup sysctl parameter in container RHEL 6.6

Tags: docker

i created an images of RHEL 6.6 (FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel6.6) but when i run a container:

```
docker run --privileged --rm -h "DAN" --net net_custom --ip 200.0.2.3 -t -i test_beta_4 bash
```

and i try to load some parameter in sysctl.conf it return the following error:

```
error: "net.core.rmem_default" is an unknown key
error: "net.core.wmem_default" is an unknown key
error: "net.core.rmem_max" is an unknown key
error: "net.core.wmem_max" is an unknown key
```

i check under /proc/sys/net/core/ and i found out those file are missing.
so how can i change those network kernel settings?
im running docker on my mac.
thanks

Comment: did you try something like ,in this doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime `docker run --sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 someimage`?

Comment: yes i did try, but this is the output:docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"open /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default: no such file or directory\"".

Answer (score 7):

This same question came up on this particular github issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30778

It seems that these net.core parameters are not something that the kernel will be able to put in a namespace. The error message comes because docker is trying to set these, in the kernel denies it.

That issue is currently active at time of writing, and it looks like the docker developers will be looping in the kernel team.

As a workaround, it looks like you should be able to set those settings on your host globally, which should then extend into all of your containers.

Comment: there is not a workaround....is a big limitation cause i can't run my container on different platform like i supposed to do.

Comment: Did you try setting the options globally on the host?

Comment: Hi, sorry what does it mean?

Comment: Rather then try to set it inside the container, set it on the host instead. Once it is set on the host, since it is a global option, it should apply to the host and all containers. Since the linux kernel does not seem to support name spacing of this option, setting it host wide is going to be the only possibility.

Comment: The problem is I'm running docker on a mac and I can't set those parameters. I should try on a rhel but then in case I wanna export my project on a different platform I will face the same problem again.